# How do you set the display name of nested classes in Python?

Tags: python, class, inner-classes

I have a scenario where I've got multiple nested classes all with the same name, and debugging it is driving me nuts.

Here's a sketch:

```
class Reference(object):
    # common functionality here

class Fruit(object):
    # common functionality here

class Apple(Fruit):
    class Ref(Reference):
        # specific functionality here

class Orange(Fruit):
    class Ref(Reference):
        # specific functionality here

# like 6 more fruits
```

My problem: any operation that lists the classname of a reference object shows it as `mymodule.Ref` and not, say, `mymodule.Apple.Ref`, which would be much more helpful.

Is there a way to tell Python to use a better name for instances of my nested classes? in default `__str__` but also in `__type__`, etc.

Bonus details:

- flattening the class structure and/or using unique names would do it, but (a) that adds namespace clutter, and (b) there are bits in Fruit that use `cls.Ref`/`self.Ref`. Suboptimal.
- it's a legacy 2.7 research system, if that matters. Actually, if 3 has fixed this that would be a useful addition to my bucket of arguments to upgrade us...

Comment: This just isn't something you would ever do in Python.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Django does it with the nested class Meta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually Python 3 did fix this with [`__qualname__`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3155/). Time to upgrade.

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3155/#example-with-nested-classes

According to the PEP rationale (*PEP 3155 -- Qualified name for classes and functions*), what you want is not possible in 2.7.